# Confluence SOAP Client connection not working

Tags: php, soap, confluence

I have the following code:

`$login = array( 
                'login' => $user,
                'password' => $pw 
        );
        $soapClient = new \SoapClient("https://confluence.com/confluence/rpc/soap-axis/pdfexport?wsdl", $login);
        $token = $soapClient->__soapCall("login", $login);
        $result = $soapClient->__soapCall("exportSpace", array("token" => $token, 'spaceKey' => "spacename"));
        print_r($result); }`

the Error message from soap is:

> SoapFault: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Post your wsdl file.

Comment: it lookes exactly like this
https://developer.atlassian.com/rpc/soap-axis/pdfexport?wsdl